# Moq.Setup Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest, legacy-code

I'm working on some legacy code (def: untested code - some well designed some not) and trying to develop some tests to confirm recent changes did what they expected etc. I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to force a method that has a try{catch} block in it to throw an exception using Moq. When I try to run the test it fails during the mock.Setup call with System.ArgumentException "Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'".

The basic setup of the code:

Interface for FilterController...

```
public interface IFilterController
{
    ActionResult DeleteFilter(string reportFilter, bool customReport = true);
}
```

FilterController class...

```
public class FilterController : BaseController, IFilterController
{
    public FilterController(
        IServiceFactory serviceFactory,
        IAwsServiceFactory awsServiceFactory,
        IReportServiceFactory reportServiceFactory,
        IAzureServiceFactory azureServiceFactory)
        : base(typeof(FilterController), serviceFactory, awsServiceFactory, reportServiceFactory, azureServiceFactory)
    {
    }

     // method under test
    public ActionResult (string reportFilter, bool customReport = true) {
        try {
             // NOTE: I have trimmed down the actual code in the try block significantly for brevity - I should be able to hook onto something here as a way to mock something throwing an exception
             var customReportFilterService = _serviceFactory.CreateCustomReportFilterService();
            var emailReportSettingService = _serviceFactory.CreateEmailReportSettingService();
            string message = string.Empty;
            JsonReturnType type = JsonReturnType.DisplayMessage; // an enum

            var filter = customReportFilterService.GetReportFilterByHash(SessionHelper.User.CustomerId, reportFilter, initLinkedProjects: true);
            return JsonActionResult(type, ajaxMessage: message, redirectTo: filter == null ? null : string.Format("Report/{0}", filter.ReportName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return JsonActionResult(JsonReturnType.Error, ajaxMessage: "There was an error in deleting the filter.");
        }
    }         
}
```

BaseController class...

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProgressController _progressController;
    protected IServiceFactory _serviceFactory;
    protected IAwsServiceFactory _awsServiceFactory;
    protected IReportServiceFactory _reportServiceFactory;
    protected IAzureServiceFactory _azureServiceFactory;
    protected IApplicationSettingService _applicationSettingService;
    protected IReportMonitorService _reportMonitorService;
    protected ISymmetricAlgorithmProvider HiddenEncrypter { get; set; }
    private Stopwatch _watch;
    private bool _timePageEnabled;
    private bool _maintenance;
    private int _pageLoadThreshold;
    private readonly ILog Logger;

    public BaseController(Type type, IServiceFactory serviceFactory, IAwsServiceFactory awsServiceFactory, IReportServiceFactory reportServiceFactory, IAzureServiceFactory azureServiceFactory)
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
        _progressController = new ProgressController();
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
        _awsServiceFactory = awsServiceFactory;
        _reportServiceFactory = reportServiceFactory;
        _azureServiceFactory = azureServiceFactory;
        _applicationSettingService = _serviceFactory.CreateApplicationSettingService();
        _reportMonitorService = _serviceFactory.CreateReportMonitorService();

        _watch = new Stopwatch();
        _timePageEnabled = _applicationSettingService.ReadApplicationSettingFromCache<bool>(CC.Data.Model.Constants.ApplicationSettings.CheckSlowPageLoad, true);
        _pageLoadThreshold = _applicationSettingService.ReadApplicationSettingFromCache<int>(CC.Data.Model.Constants.ApplicationSettings.PageLoadThreshold, 120);
        _maintenance = _applicationSettingService.MaintenanceMode();
    }

   // System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult type mentioned in error
   public ActionResult JsonActionResult(JsonReturnType returnType, string view = null, string ajaxMessage = null, string redirectTo = null, string target = null, object data = null, string popupTitle = null)
    {
        if (returnType == JsonReturnType.LoadContent)
           _progressController.CompleteProgressCache();

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

        var resultData = new { 
            ReturnType = returnType, 
            HtmlView = view, 
            Message = ajaxMessage, 
            RedirectTo = redirectTo, 
            Target = target, 
            CustomData = data, 
            ProjectId = SessionHelper.ProjectId, 
            PopupTitle = popupTitle,
            MaintenanceMode = _maintenance
        };

        ContentResult result;

        result = new ContentResult
        {
                Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData),
                ContentType = "application/json"
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

Controller class...

```
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, IResultFilter {
    // stuff
}
```

Unit Test class...

```
[TestClass]
public class FilterControllerTest
{
    private FilterController filterController;
    private Mock<IFilterController> filterControllerMock;

    private Mock<IServiceFactory> serviceFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IAwsServiceFactory> awsServiceFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IReportServiceFactory> reportServiceFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IAzureServiceFactory> azureServiceFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IApplicationSettingService> applicationSettingServiceMock;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
    {
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        filterControllerMock = new Mock<IFilterController>();
        serviceFactoryMock = new Mock<IServiceFactory>();
        awsServiceFactoryMock = new Mock<IAwsServiceFactory>();
        reportServiceFactoryMock = new Mock<IReportServiceFactory>();
        azureServiceFactoryMock = new Mock<IAzureServiceFactory>();
        applicationSettingServiceMock = new Mock<IApplicationSettingService>();

        serviceFactoryMock
            .Setup(s => s.CreateApplicationSettingService())
            .Returns(applicationSettingServiceMock.Object);

        filterController = new FilterController(
            serviceFactoryMock.Object
            , awsServiceFactoryMock.Object
            , reportServiceFactoryMock.Object
            , azureServiceFactoryMock.Object);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
    }

    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteFilter_ExceptionThrown_IsCaughtAndLoggedAndReturnsActionResultOfError()
    {

        // Arrange
        filterControllerMock
            .Setup(x => x.DeleteFilter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Throws(new Exception());

        // Act
        var result = filterController.DeleteFilter("myfilt", false);
    }
}
```

In the end all I want to do is have it so when DeleteFilter is called for this test, an error is thrown and then I can assert what is returned from the catch block.

EDIT: have majorly updated the post by suggestion to make it easier to understand where the issue is.

Comment: According to the example `IFilterController` interface doesn't have a `TestMethod` method defined. it only has `DeleteFilter` defined

Comment: Also your unit test is incomplete. I see no relation between the mock you setup and your concrete class.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue and the expected behavior.

Comment: Sorry, was replacing the actual method name with TestMethod. updated OP. Could you clarify how the unit test is incomplete? It is my understanding the filterControllerMock should set it up so once testMethod is called by the filterController object (setup elsewhere in the test initialization - I just pass in mocked Interfaces for parameters), that it should just perform the mocked section of it and throw an exception.

Comment: I'll edit to provide more detail - again, this is legacy code so it is pretty damn ugly at times. I was hoping the amount of information provided could at least help me understand why I am getting the weird error message I am

Comment: no that is not how it's done. Show the test initialization code. You typically want to mock up the dependencies of your system under test. so far the example you are showing has no obvious dependencies

Comment: Based on your updated example `filterController` and `filterControllerMock` are in no way related in the ocntext of the unit test. Is any of the dependencies executing with the try portion of the example `//stuff`. that it where you need to setup your mock exception. you don't even need to mock `IFilterController` in this test

Comment: Guess I wasn't correctly understanding what the mock.Setup().Throws() was doing. Was basing my understanding off an article I read (http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/mock-exceptions-using-moq). I see the main difference there is when calling the class, it injects the mock object. Though it has the interface and classes setup differently enough to allow this. Perhaps that is what should be done anyways. I'm very inexperienced with refactoring to extract an interface so was hoping to for now just get a working test for this.

Comment: Doing up an example now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slimmed down example

Given

```
public interface IServiceFactory {
    object GetService(string args);
}

public class MyController : Controller {
    IServiceFactory serviceFactory

    public MyController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory) {
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

     // method under test
    public ActionResult DeleteFilter(string args) {
        try {
            var model = serviceFactory.GetService(args);
            return View(model);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           return JsonActionResult(JsonReturnType.Error, ajaxMessage: "There was an error in deleting the filter.");
        }
    }         
}
```

You can use moq in your test like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteFilter_ExceptionThrown_IsCaughtAndLoggedAndReturnsActionResultOfError() {
    // Arrange
    var serviceFactoryMock = new Mock<IServiceFactory>();
    serviceFactoryMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetService(It.IsAny<string>())
        .Throws(new Exception())
        .Verifiable();

    var controller = new MyController(serviceFactoryMock.Object);

    // Act
    var result = controller.DeleteFilter("blah blah");

    //Assert
    serviceFactoryMock.Verify(); // verifies that the setup was invoked
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(JsonActionResult));
    //...other assertions
}
```

So now in the example when `DeleteFilter` is called, the mock service factory is invoked, an error is thrown based on the setup and you can assert what is returned from the catch block.